# How to find the max value in one column based on the value in another? SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with

```
Repcode  ID     LastUpdateDate
ABCD     ADAMA  12/6/2019
EFG      ERINA  13/6/2019
ABCD     ADAMA  14/6/2019
TOM      TERRY  12/4/2019
SAM      SAMMY  12/6/2019
TOM      SLIPP  24/10/2013
ABCD     BALLP  22/4/2010
```

For each Repcode, I need the latest ID based on the LastUpdateDate. One row per RepCode

```
Repcode ID      LastUpdateDate
ABCD    ADAMA   14/6/2019
EFG     ERINA   13/6/2019
SAM     SAMMY   12/6/2019
TOM     TERRY   12/4/2019
```

The Repcodes are reused so the underlying ID may change over time.

```
WITH summary AS (
  SELECT m.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY m.lastupdatedate DESC) AS rank
    FROM Mtable m
    )

SELECT distinct s.repCode, s.id, LastUpdateDate
  FROM summary s
```

but I'm not getting a condensed result like I expect with just the latest repcode/id based on the max lastupdatedate. Please help, thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `select distinct`.  You want a `where` clause and a `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
WITH summary AS (
      SELECT m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.repcode ORDER BY m.lastupdatedate DESC) AS rank
      FROM Mtable m
     )
SELECT s.repCode, s.id, LastUpdateDate
FROM summary s
WHERE rank = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select s.*
from summary s
where not exists (
  select 1 from summary
  where repcode = s.repcode and lastupdatedate > s.lastupdatedate
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You coudl try also using a inner join  on the max

```
select  m.* 
from  Mtable m
inner join  (

  select  Repcode, ID, max(LastUpdateDate ) max_date 
  from  Mtable 
  group by   Repcode, ID 

  ) t on t.Repcode = m.Repcode 
        and t.id = m.id     
          and t.max_date  = m.LastUpdateDate
```

Answer (score 0):

With `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause:

`SELECT * FROM summary GROUP BY Repcode HAVING MAX(LastUpdateDate)`